# Serializing a block of text django rest-framework and displaying paragraphs with react

Tags: json, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, format

I am creating a blog and using djangorestframework as my backend and react for my frontend. When I serialize my data, I lose the formatting for my blog enteries (which are written in paragraphs). Is there a way to fix this.

So:

**Blog Post**

```
This is my blog post, and this is my formatting.

My second paragraph.
```

becomes.

```
[{ 
   "title": "blog post",
   content: "This is my blog post, and this is my formatting My second paragraph."
}
]
```

When i pass it through my react it remains

```
This is my blog post, and this is my formatting My second paragraph.
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you should define your contend field type as [*TextField*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField) in your model.

**Something like this**

```
content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the formatting problem by using django-tinymce in my projects with the HTMLField in my models. You can serialize the tinyMCE.HTMLField into a simple serializers.CharField. Then you need to have a plugin in your react frontend, it can be any editor of your choice, tinymce, ckeditor or other less robust editors to have the text entry formatted and submitted with the formatting tags to your backend.